# name of elliptic pde with a power law nonlinearity

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Consider an equation like

$$-\Delta u = |u|^p u  $$  in $\Omega$  with $u=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$  where $\Omega$ a domain in $ R^N$ and $ u:\Omega \rightarrow R^N$.     Here $p$ is arbitrary or maybe $p=2$.   Or consider Neumann problems like this with a zero order term $u$ added to the left.

Do these equations have a name?  (I am interested in what kind of results are known and I have no clue what to google).  thank you very much.

Comment: I would search "semilinear elliptic equation." There are many classical results due to Gidas, Nirenberg, Spruck, Wei-Ming Ni, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case $p=2$ is the [nonlinear Schrödinger equation,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) more generally written as
$$Eu=-\Delta u+\kappa|u|^2 u,$$
with coefficients $E,\kappa\in\mathbb R$. It describes the propagation of light in nonlinear optical fibers and is also a model for a superfluid. In the one-dimensional case the equation can be solved exactly for $\kappa<0$. It supports socalled "soliton" solutions, localized in space.
 <sub>As written the differential equation applies to harmonic solutions $\propto e^{-iEt}$ in the time domain; alternatively, consider functions of both space and time and replace the left-hand-side of the equation by $i\partial u/\partial t$.</sub>

Generalizations with $p$ an even integer are also studied in this context, see for example [Schrödinger equation with a power-law nonlinearity.](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/npde/npde1402.pdf)

Comment: is $u$ here a scalar or vector?

Comment: both cases are considered in the literature, for the vectorial nonlinear Schrödinger equation, see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2990

Comment: do you have any references for the purely elliptic problem on a bounded domain with $u=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$.  (ie.  $-\Delta u= |u|^p u$ in $\Omega$) where $u$ a vector and where they discuss existence of nonzero solutions and $p$.